# three.js - repeating a SECTION of a texture atlas

Tags: three.js, textures, texture-mapping, texture-atlas

So in three.js it seems we need to use the texture.offset and texture.repeat properies to extract sections of a texture(atlas) for applying to different meshes. This works fine, but as far as I can tell it is impossible to then choose to repeat that section of the texture? because the repeat property is already being used to define the "edge" of the texture sub-section.
My code for using texture.offset and texture.repeat to extract a section of a texture:`

```
var texture = atlasTexture.clone();
texture.repeat.set(section.w / atlasTexture.width, section.h / atlasTexture.height);
texture.offset.x = ((section.x) / atlasTexture.width);
texture.offset.y = 1 - (section.h / atlasTexture.height) - (section.y / atlasTexture.height);
```

Comment: Have a look at this [example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=cube#webgl_panorama_cube) to see how to work with a texture altas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer.. you can't without using a custom shader... and making custom shaders is more painful than it could be IMO. You have to make the region information visible to the shader, by encoding a tile index in the UV coordinate or something..
either by using fixed size tiles.. You also have to worry about padding the islands if you want the texture filtering to not give you edge artifacts. I've done this before for a hexmap tile rendering engine I wrote a while ago... and it was fiddly to get working but when I did, it performed Really well.. I had maps of 4k/4k tiles running at 60fps with 3 layers.

If you want to discuss it further live, I hang out in this slack of three.js devs.. my nick is thrax.

https://join.slack.com/t/threejs/shared_invite/enQtMzYxMzczODM2OTgxLWE5OTU4OTYxZTZlODk1ZGNjODIyMDZlODM4ZmUyMzNiOWIxMmFjNTYwOTc4MjU0ZmNiODk5MzZiMGJhMTkzZWI

Comment: Damn. I was hoping some combination of geometry UV settings + texture map offset/repeat could make this work. The only problem with custom shaders is that I still want to use all the other great aspects of Standard Material (normal maps, lighting etc). Maybe there is a way to "extend" the standard Material shader? rather than starting from scratch.

Comment: https://medium.com/@pailhead011/extending-three-js-materials-with-glsl-78ea7bbb9270